# HTML/JavaScript Inline Validation doesn't work fully

Tags: javascript, html

I have HTML/JavaScript code that mostly works but not 100 percent. If I put invalid characters in the name field, it gives an error as expected. But, if I enter an invalid character first and then type valid characters in, It wouldn't throw any errors. It basically accepts it. Why is that? How do I fix it? I have this code:

```
<script>
function validateName(x){
  var re = /[A-Za-z -']$/;
  if(re.test(document.getElementById(x).value)){
  document.getElementById(x).style.background ='#ccffcc';
  document.getElementById(x + 'Error').style.display = "none";
  return true;
  }else{
  document.getElementById(x).style.background ='#e35152';
   document.getElementById(x + 'Error').style.display = "block";
   return false; 
  }
}
function validateForm(){
 var error = 0;
 if(!validateName('name')){
    document.getElementById('nameError').style.display = "block";
    error++;
  }
</scipt>
<form action="" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
<fieldset>
  <label for="name">Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" onblur="validateName(name)" />
  <span id="nameError" style="display: none;">You can only use alphabetic characters, hyphens and apostrophes</span>
</fieldset>
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Use RegEx101](https://regex101.com/).

Comment: @Xufox what does it mean?

Comment: RegEx debugging and analyzing tool. Use this if you have any RegEx questions next time and look at the [RegEx tag-wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your test:

```
/[A-Za-z -']$/
```

says:

*Either a letter, a space, a hyphen or an apostrophe, followed by the end of the string.*

So it doesn't matter what any character other than the last one is.

You need to start the expression with a `^` if you want to anchor it to the start of the string (as well as using `$` to anchor it to the end).

You may want to add `*` or `+` after the group so that you can have more than a single character in it.

Comment: thanks for the answer. So what is the expression gonna be?
    /[^A-Za-z -']$/

Comment: No. I said **start** (in the same way as the `$` is at the end). `/^[A-Za-z -']$/`

Comment: @KhatarnaakGunda — By "weird behaviour" do you mean everything that I discussed in the last paragraph of the answer?

Comment: Actually I need to scratch that. I made a mistake. You were right. Sorry about that.
edit: it didn't show me any edit button so I deleted it.